# Angular | Partially import aws-sdk in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm using the aws-sdk in my Angular application.
The bundle size is HUGE, and I'm only using a tiny fraction of the library:

[image]

**Question:** Is there any way to only partially import aws-sdk?

Please note:

- I cannot use ['customize & download'](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/), since I'm using Amplify (which has aws-sdk as dependency)
- I currently import AWS the following way: `import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';`
- I only use Cognito, S3, Lambda, DynamoDB and IoT Core

Comment: How did you generate that image?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, you can import individual parts of the AWS SDK like so:

```
// import individual service
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
```

You'll need to consult the documentation / type definitions to see what the ones you want are called exactly.

Avoid importing the whole "aws-sdk" package as this won't be tree shaken

Answer (score 0):

In my application I use only S3. And I managed to reduce the size of the bundle as follows:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/global';
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

//Here is an example of code used to perform file upload.

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "YOUR-ACCESS-KEY",
    secretAccessKey: "YOUR-SECRET",
    "region": "us-east-1"  
}); 

var file = document.getElementById("input-upload").files[0];
var bucket = new S3({params: {Bucket: 'mybucket'}});
var params = {Key: 'myfolder', ContentType: file.type, Body: file};

bucket.upload(params);
```

[image]